# Making redirection in the REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, redirect

I wanted to create an interceptor for several addresses that will check if the user is logged in and if not, it will redirect him to another page.

```
registry.addInterceptor(new CheckLoginStatus()).addPathPatterns("/messages/*");
```

I use this interceptor for REST API addresses, so the console throws me an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
```

The redirection I do in this way

```
RequestDispatcher dd = request.getRequestDispatcher("signIn.html");

dd.forward(request, response);
```

Is it possible to create an incereptora that will redirect to another address?

Comment: Try  httpResponse.sendRedirect("signIn.html");

Comment: Now throw exception 'Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed'.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect more than one time? Can you please paste code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j0TALggc

Comment: You need to include RedirectAttributes in signature, had same problem not a long ago